# MATLAB plotting trajectory

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to plot the angular velocity of point B by using MATLAB. However, there is some mistake in my code for angular velocity that I couldn't fix.

[image]

The length of the input link OA of the mechanism is r = 50 mm, length of AB is l = 150 mm. Fixed coordinates of point C are xC = d = 80 mm and yC = 0 mm.
Angular velocity of OA is ω = 15 rad/s.

```
   %Full trajectory of B

%Linkage dimensions

clear
r = 50;
l = 150;
xC = 80;
yC = 0;
n = 361; % Number of position calculations
fii = linspace(0,2*pi,n);
omega = 15;
[xA,yA] = pol2cart(fii,r);
d = xA + xC;

alpha = atan(yA./(xC-xA));

lx = l*cos(alpha);
ly = l*sin(alpha);

xB = xA + lx;
yB = yA + ly;

plot(xB,yB) %Plots the trajectory

title('Full trajectory of AB')

% Angular velocity of AB 

for ind = 1:n
omegaAB(ind) = (-(r^2-d*r*cos(fii))/(r^2 + d^2 - 2*d*r*cos(fii)))*omega;
end

figure(2)
plot(fii,omegaAB, 'linewidth', 2, 'color', 'red')
title('Angular velocity of AB')
ylabel('\omega_{AB} [1/s]')
xlabel('\phi [rad]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is just one mistake in your code when you compute `alpha`:

```
alpha = atan(yA./(xC-xA));
```

This gives the following trajectory:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is partially vectorized but you're still looping over `ind` which is why you are getting matrix dimensions errors.  You can either remove the loop and make it completely vectorized or you can make sure that all of your vectors with length `n` are indexed properly:

```
for ind = 1:n
    omegaAB(ind) = (-(r^2-d*r*cos(fii(ind)))/(r^2 + d(ind)^2 - 2*d*r*cos(fii(ind))))*omega;
end
```

[image]